listview builder doesn't take full height inside column
i am using listview.builder inside column widget, my column contains a text and then listview.builder widget (inside Sizedbox), the problem is i want to take full available height (according to device height) how can this be done?

 return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            title: Text(
              'RAM FOOTBALL',
              style: GoogleFonts.anton(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Matches',
                  style: GoogleFonts.anton(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 500,
                child: ListView.builder()


You can use media queries to adjust the height instead of using a static height of 500.

Just wrap that ListView with Expanded widget like the following:
 Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Matches',
                      style: GoogleFonts.anton(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                   Expanded(
                     child: ListView.builder()...
                        )
            ....

For sure, you now should remove that sized box.
